# TypeScript union of strings not assignable to union of tuples in function

Tags: typescript, tuples

The behaviour of these two examples should be identical, yet the second one errors. Why?

```
// Example 1:
const a: 'x' | 'y' = 'x'; 
const b: ['x'] | ['y'] = [a]; // ok

// Example 2:
function fn(a: 'x' | 'y') {
  const b: ['x'] | ['y'] = [a];
  //    ^
  // Type '["x" | "y"]' is not assignable to type '["x"] | ["y"]'.
  //   Type '["x" | "y"]' is not assignable to type '["x"]'.
  //     Type '"x" | "y"' is not assignable to type '"x"'.
  //       Type '"y"' is not assignable to type '"x"'.
}
```

You can [try it on the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=const%20a%3A%20'x'%20%7C%20'y'%20%3D%20'x'%3B%20%0Aconst%20b%3A%20%5B'x'%5D%20%7C%20%5B'y'%5D%20%3D%20%5Ba%5D%3B%0A%0Afunction%20fn(a%3A%20'x'%20%7C%20'y')%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20const%20b%3A%20%5B'x'%5D%20%7C%20%5B'y'%5D%20%3D%20%5Ba%5D%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A).

Comment: I would think `'x' | 'y'` would map more naturally to `['x' | 'y']`, and that does work: `const b: ['x' | 'y'] = [a];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UPDATE: 2019-05-30 the release of TypeScript 3.5 introduces [smarter union type checking](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#smarter-union-type-checking) which fixes this for object types (like `{a: "x"} | {a: "y"}`, but doesn't seem to do anything to tuple types (like `["x"] | ["y"]`).  Not sure if that's intentional or not.

---

In "Example 1", the fact that `a` is initialized to `"x"` makes a big difference.  The control flow analysis narrows the type of `a` down to just `"x"` despite your annotation as `"x" | "y"`:

```
let a: "x" | "y" = "x";
console.log(a === "y"); // error!
// This condition will always return 'false' 
// since the types '"x"' and '"y"' have no overlap.
```

So then of course in this case `[a]` will match `["x"] | ["y"]`, since `[a]` is known by the compiler to be of type `["x"]`.

---

Therefore, Example 1 only succeeds coincidentally. In general, this fails.  The compiler does not generally see `[A] | [B]` as equivalent to `[A | B]`.  The former is seen as a strictly narrower type than the latter.

```
type Extends<T, U extends T> = true;
type OkayTup = Extends<[string | number], [string] | [number]>; 
type NotOkayTup = Extends<[string] | [number], [string | number]>; // error!
```

This may be surprising, since in fact every value of type `[A | B]` should be assignable to type `[A] | [B]`.  This same surprise happens when you look at the analogous property-bag version:

```
type OkayObj = Extends<{a: string | number}, {a: string} | {a: number}>;
type NotOkayObj = Extends<{a: string} | {a: number}, {a: string | number}>; // error!
```

Again, `{a: A} | {a: B}` is seen to be a strictly narrower type than `{a: A | B}`, despite the fact that you'd be hard pressed to come up with a value of the latter type that wasn't assignable to the former.

So, what's going on here?  Well, it seems that this is either [intentional](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12052) or a [design limitation](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8289#issuecomment-214554425) of TypeScript.  The [Word of Language Architect](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12052#issuecomment-258653766) says:

> For your example to type check with no errors we would have to consider types of the form `{ x: "foo" | "bar" }` to be equivalent to `{ x: "foo" } | { x: "bar" }`. But this sort of equivalence only holds for types with a single property and isn't true in the general case. For example, it wouldn't be correct to consider `{ x: "foo" | "bar", y: string | number }` to be equivalent to `{ x: "foo", y: string } | { x: "bar", y: number }` because the first form allows all four combinations whereas the second form only allows two specific ones.

(Note: the equivalence holds in slightly more cases than mentioned above... it only applies where the properties that are *different* in each union constituent take on all possible values of the union in the single-property case.  So, `{x: string | number, y: boolean, z: string}` is equivalent to `{x: string, y: true, z: string} | {x: string, y: false, z: string} | {x: number, y: true, z: string} | {x: number, y: false, z: string}`)

I'd say this is a design limitation... detecting the relatively rare cases where property unions can be collapsed/expanded would be very expensive, and it's just not worth it to implement.

---

In practice, if you find yourself faced with a union property merge thingy that the compiler doesn't verify but that you know is safe, demonstrate your superior intellect and [assert](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) your way out of it:

```
function fn(a: 'x' | 'y') {
  const b = [a] as ['x'] | ['y'] // I'm smarter than the compiler  
}
```

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!