# Why doesn't TypeScript `Exclude<T, U>` exclude? Is this a bug?

Tags: typescript, union-types

This is hard to explain, but I'm trying to filter out a certain type in a subfield of an object type.

`Exclude<T, U>` doesn't seem to work with this kind of nesting:

```
type PrivateName = { kind: "PrivateName" };
type Identifier = { kind: "Identifier" };

type NamedNode = {
  name: PrivateName | Identifier;
};

type PrivateNamedNode = {
  name: PrivateName;
};

declare const privateName: PrivateName;

type NamedNodeNonPrivate = Exclude<NamedNode, PrivateNamedNode>;

// I expected this next line to error, but it doesn't!
const x: NamedNodeNonPrivate = { name: privateName };
```

Why didn't the last line error? Should I open a bug report?

Tested on TS versions: 3.5.1, 3.3.3, 3.1.6, and 3.0.1. [playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgSwG4ENgQHIoLbQLxQDeUA1ggHYAmAXFAETzJqY4R1QC+A3ALABQoSFACSlCOWAIAZgghwoBYmSq06o8ZJlz23fv0HQsuShgD2YhUX5Qo5VrUap0R6AB8RYidNlxefXXz64NCOzC4m5vhWfDZ2uA6ITiy4fgFBQhgYloTWtvawiWGs-BxQ7jkxefEeGt5yJXqBfGIAxgA2KHDQLabkAM7AUGCFzvmhoymNBlDhZmJm5ONRAKIAHu0ArmIAPLORADQFTBMQEWIAfH78Pf2Dq7R7871L2VUQtMPHydBpAsFQLQAFhAWiRLI9oBBVugqH0jkkIVAAPxQADMUFoAFYrn8hChwawzpDoeJKHDiHF3vCirhOMi0RioNigA).

### Potential Root Cause

The definition of `Exclude<T, U>` is

```
/**
 * Exclude from T those types that are assignable to U
 */
type Exclude<T, U> = T extends U ? never : T;
```

It seems to be inert in my example because `NamedNode` doesn't extend `{ name: PrivateName }`.

Changing the definition as follows produces the desired error message. Unfortunately, this isn't a refactor I can do manually to the whole codebase:

```
type NamedNode = {
  name: PrivateName
} | {
  name: Identifier
}
```

The Curry-Howard Isomorphism tells us that product types are like conjunction and sum types are like disjunction.

The following holds in Boolean logic:

`A & (B or C)    implies    (A & B) or (A & C)`

So it seems reasonable that the two definitions of NamedNode would be equivalent. Is this lack of distributivity:

- **1** the cause of my problem above
- **2** a bug?

Answer (score 1):

`{ name: PrivateName | Identifier; };` and `{ name: PrivateName } | { name: Identifier }` are equivalent only in the trivial case when there object type contains only this property. The common use case is that the different branches of the union will hold different type.

Regardless of this, conditional types do [distribute](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) but only over naked type parameters. No magic distribution occurs over properties of every type. And since the relation `NamedNode extends PrivateNamedNode` is not true no types will be excluded (no type can be excluded since `NamedNode` is not  a union, even if the relation were true, you would get `never` since then the whole type would be excluded and you would be left with nothing).

We can build a type that excludes types from properties of an object:

```
type PrivateName = { kind: "PrivateName" };
type Identifier = { kind: "Identifier" };

type NamedNode = {
    name: PrivateName | Identifier;
};

type PrivateNamedNode = {
    name: PrivateName;
};

declare const privateName: PrivateName;

type ExcludePropertyTypes<T, TExclude extends Partial<T>> {
    [P in keyof T]: Exclude<T[P], TExclude[P]>
}

type NamedNodeNonPrivate = ExcludePropertyTypes<NamedNode, PrivateNamedNode>;

// Errors now (as intended)
const x: NamedNodeNonPrivate = { name: privateName };
```

[Playground link](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgSwG4ENgQHIoLbQLxQDeUA1ggHYAmAXFAETzJqY4R1QC+A3AFCiRQAkpQjlgCAGYIIcKAWJkqtOsNHipM9tx59w0LLkoYA9iLlEeUK1HKtajVOgPQAPkJFjJ0uL226BDszORqb4FtY2drCIjiy4vrw8IgDGADYocNDJxuQAzsBQYDFBUYFOrIn80ACiAB5pAK4i8MaQcKAAKnq5ADwdADRQHXWNZhC16FS5sBniKKl9AHyL4dYA2jBQFKQQIMYSQwC6tCOpTRB9G4eDw-VnIleLPBw6VVDBJiIm5GVhp+ctNqdbo9D6hQa-MEiRaJAD0sKEUHGkGS6EoUGAAAsENNyOMCqkKNBgMYkXA4MY4IMAEYNAoIAqUYwQXLkADkwAAhDxsnkCrVaFDMDlfuZiLZcLQikxyrhOFwgA)

Comment: @max-heiber 10x for the edit, for to edit the comment 

Comment: Thanks for your answer, good resource, and helpful helper function. But I feel this doesn't really address the concern: You linked to distributivity of conditional over unions, but that doesn't explain why is-property-of doesn't distribute over unions. You said '...doesn't magically' but I don't see why magic would have to be involved. Couldn't this be fixed, at least for small types? In particular, if TS normalized types internally such that the two representations of `NamedNode` have the same normal form, we'd get this for free.

Comment: @MaxHeiber You can open a suggestion on GH for this, but I suspect there is no appetite for this, as except for single property types, such a normalization would explode the type count. Consider a type with 5 properties with 5 members in each property type union, the resulting union would be huge.

Comment: I guess I don't have good intuitions around hugeness yet. Theoretically, everything can be done lazily. There are 3125 combinations in the example you gave, but that's true regardless of whether unions are normalized: https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBvAUFLUCGAuKARigB8oAmUqAZioBYqBWAbk2wCMDizKzayGZFmywBjLlV416TVtigATCTyr8ogqMPkRlFVTKGsAvulOi4AOwDOwKAA8C8RClS4uAGiicKn8TU9K6p46mkZAA

Comment: [Relevant issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12052), and a [relevant comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8289#issuecomment-214554425) (from an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56174696/typescript-union-of-strings-not-assignable-to-union-of-tuples-in-function/56175262#56175262) I gave to a related question)